# Como "puxar" uma Branch da origin sem dar git pull?

Tags: git, versionamento

Eu estou em um projeto conjunto, na origin foi criada uma branch da qual eu não tenho no PC, como copiar essa Branch para minha maquina sem ter que dar um pull ?
Gostaria de ter a Branch exatamente como ela está, sem dar merge.

Oque eu geralmente faço é ir para master, criar uma nova Branch e dar git pull origin [branchDesejada]. Mas não quero, quero ter a Branch com o nome e alterações que estão na origin.

Comment: Apesar do título da pergunta sugerida acima não parecer ter relação com o problema, a resposta está lá (basta usar o `git fetch`)

Comment: certinho amigos, muito obrigado. Acho bom deixar a pergunta aberta para aqueles que não sabem o nome do comando para pesquisarem a diferença